# Syncrify and SSL support

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync, ssl

I installed the Syncrify server and client on a Linux box.

From what I've read on their site, Syncrify comes with a built in self-signed SSL certificate. However after setting the SSL port on the Syncrify Admin Set-Up, I am still unable to login with a client through SSL.

This works: (5800 is the default port for HTTP)

- http://host.com:5800

However the following do not work:

- https://host.com:443
- https://host.com

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Ubuntu comes with a default state of all ports being blocked. Although the firewall was off, it was still blocking all incoming connections.

I turned the firewall on, allowed port 443, and now it's working!